# How do I dynamically modify a mutline bash command?

Tags: bash

I've got the below bash script that invokes Docker. I would like to omit or include the `--env-file` line based on whether or not the `secrets.docker.env` file is encoded. I have the test to decide if the file is encoded working, but now I'm not sure if it's even possible to have an if statement add/remove part of a command.

Perhaps I could store the line of text as a HEREDOC, edit the line to remove the one I don't want, and then `bash -c` to evaluate it and get all the proper substitution.

EDIT-> This worked for me, after taking advice from the comments below from Charles Duffy

```
COMMAND_ARRAY=(docker run --rm=true --net=host --user="$(id -u)":"$(id -g)" -e BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER:=-1} -e TERM=${TERM} ${EXTRA_DOCKER_COMMANDS} ${TERMINAL_COMMAND} --workdir="$(pwd)" --volume=/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --volume=/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd --volume=/etc/group:/etc/group $GROUP_ADDS --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume=/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime --ulimit nofile=262144 --volume="${HOME}":"${HOME}" --volume="${GITROOT}":"${GITROOT}" ${IMAGE_NAME}:${VERSION} "$@")

"${COMMAND_ARRAY[@]}"
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), entries #3 and #5

Comment: BTW, putting a comment in a command substitution is a *really* inefficient way to embed a comment (you're `fork()`ing off a whole new copy of the shell just to run the comment!)

Comment: `extra_args=( ); [ -e secrets.docker.env ] && extra_args+=( --env-file "secrets.docker.env ); docker run "${extra_args[@]}" ...`

Comment: Or: `[ -e secrets.docker.env ] && env_file=secrets.docker.env; docker run ${env_file+--env-file "$env_file"}`

Comment: ...but wrt. comments -- consider defining your *entire* argument list as an array; you can put a regular comment after an array entry without worrying about needing a line continuation character at the end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Putting it all into an array worked. I'm amazed it didn't explode.

Comment: The unquoted expansions in that array are potentially buggy for the reasons described in the FAQ; if you have `EXTRA_DOCKER_COMMANDS=' --arg="something with spaces" '`, f/e, that's going to behave very badly; whereas `extra_docker_commands=( --arg="something with spaces" )` and then expanding as `"${extra_docker_commands[@]}"` is reliable.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/, and following the links in its results.

Comment: (btw, re: use of lowercase variable names in my examples, see the relevant section of the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that regular shell variables and environment variables share a single namespace; all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system, whereas names with at least one character are reserved for application use).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Did you mean to say "whereas names with at least one ~lowercase~ character are reserved for application use"?

Comment: Yup, that is indeed the word I left out.